# Codekit Jade Compilation Issues

Tags: pug, yaml, jekyll, codekit

I'm attempting to compile a layout file for a static Jekyll/Github Pages project:

```
| ---
| layout: default
| ---

header.page-header
  h1 {{ page.title }}

...etc.
```

to:

```
(skipped line)    
---
layout: default
---
<header class="page-header">
  <h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>

...etc.
```

But codekit is adding an indent at the beginning of the compiled file (so the compiled file starts on line 2). If I change the Jade to a more basic file, I still get the same issue:

[test.html](https://app.box.com/s/u52jcw40es6tisz2gee5)

The extra line means that the YAML front header isn't recognized. Does anyone know a work around or a way to fix this?

P.s. I also tried changing the codekit settings to minify and I get [this](https://app.box.com/s/wtiusmy6x6mdlwz7lwfs), which unfortunately causes the same problem

Solution: For now, I switched back to html and am no longer using jade, but if anyone has a solution their help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found this issue https://github.com/jadejs/jade/issues/1401 and solution that works for me:

Jade template:

```
:verbatim
    ---
    layout: default
    ---

h1 {{ page.title }}
```

Compiled html:

```
---
layout: default
---

<h1>{{ page.title }}</h1>
```

Tested with grunt-contrib-jade and native jekyll build.